# Just start HelloWorld display in MacOS application development

Tags: swift, macos

[Tutorial for Hello World](https://www.raywenderlich.com/151741/macos-development-beginners-part-1)

I tried using the tutorial, link described above which was going until the execution but when i use the button click to display the name it show some error

> Failed to connect (sayButtonClicked) outlet from
>   (HelloWorld.ViewController) to (NSButton): missing setter or instance
>   variable

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var nameField: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var helloLabel: NSTextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

    @IBAction func sayButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        var name = nameField.stringValue
        if name.isEmpty{
        name = "World"
        }

        let greeting = "Hello\(name)!"
        helloLabel.stringValue = greeting
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have an **outlet** connection in your storyboard named "sayButtonClicked" but "sayButtonClicked" is an IBAction, not an outlet. Try doing the following:

1. Delete that "sayButtonClicked" outlet from your storyboard.
2. Open your storyboard in the editor and the source-code for the view controller in an "assistant editor"
3. Control-drag from the dot next to your IBAction in your code onto the button in your storyboard. This will connect the action to the button. You may need to select "touch up inside" as the event you want to trigger the action.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Did it solve your problem? If so you should accept it.